# How to order categories in Woocommerce that are spread over multiple pages?

Tags: categories, plugins

I'm building a store using Woocommerce and need to manage a large number of product categories.

I would like to re-order them to appear in alphabetical order. However the drag and drop ordering system splits categories over several pages and I can't seem to find a way of editing the entire list rather or move items from one page to another.

Is there any way I can do this? If so how is it done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under [screen options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Screens#Screen_Options) on the Product Categories page, change the number of product categories to something big enough to get job done; drag and drop to order; change back to 20 or something manageable.

Answer (score 0):

The only options you have are to work within the product category page. But that page supports ordering by name, description, slug, and product count. So I'm not really sure what the issue is; just click on the 'Name' heading.

Edit -

Ordering the categories here control the 'default' listing view on the front-end. However if a user selects a sort order different than the 'default' the user's preferences override the system wide settings.

If you can not see the items in the order you are setting in the back-end scroll to the bottom on a 'category' page and select 'default' in the drop down.

Comment: Thank you but those options only change the current view, not the permanent ordering of the categories or how they display on the site.

Comment: That is not correct @JamesO'Neill, see my edits above.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

`[product_categories number="" orderby="slug" order="asc"]`

the secret was slug instead of name